# Multiple like condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

When i use multiple like condition with AND keyword, it will return false value actually, it had value in table and my query as below:

```
  SELECT * FROM tbl_student 
  WHERE name LIKE '%jame%' 
  AND ( id LIKE '%001%' 
        AND id2 LIKE '%002%'
       )
```

This query return empty row

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_student 
WHERE name LIKE '%jame%' 
OR ( id LIKE '%001%' 
     AND id2 LIKE '%002%'
   )
```

This query return data

```
tbl_student
Name         ID      ID2
jame          233     3234 
jame333       1001    0222
jame333 Da    1001    1002
```

Why it is returned empty data when use AND keyword ?

Comment: @cnjamE it does return row see at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/806f07/2

Comment: your simple should display all name has jame name but it doesn't display all records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query with the `AND` operator does not return the desired data, because your conditions placed within brackets always evaluate to false.

The reason this occurs is because you are trying to use `LIKE '%str%'` on an integer. This will not work expectedly. If you insist on using `LIKE`, you might want to [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) your integers to strings:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl_student 
 WHERE name LIKE '%jame%' 
   AND (CAST(id AS CHAR) LIKE '%001%' AND
        CAST(id2 AS CHAR) LIKE '%002%');
```

---

FYI, an `e1 AND (e2 AND e3)` logical expression remains the **same** with the brackets omitted.

Comment: CAST won't help:  mysql> SELECT 123 LIKE '%2%', 999 LIKE '%2%', '123' LIKE '%2%'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  123 LIKE '%2%': 1
  999 LIKE '%2%': 0
'123' LIKE '%2%': 1

Comment: When doing `<int> LIKE '...'`, the <int> is converted to a string.  That is, CAST is unnecessary.  (Sorry about the horrible formatting.)  I wonder if cnjamE has tried it with and without CAST.

Comment: @RickJames I see. Yeah, you can avoid the overhead of a function call with that approach.